# Reference error firestore is not defined in firebase cloud function when using firebase admin sdk

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function in which I am listening to the onCreate event of a firestore collection. When the cloud function is triggered I am getting a reference error. Below are the cloud function code and the error.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const { firestore } = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://my-app-id.firebaseio.com', // Here I have replaced my real id for privacy
})

const db = admin.firestore()

exports.handleDiscussionReplyAdded = functions.firestore
  .document('/discussions/{discussionId}/replies/{replyId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    try {
      // 1. Creating a ref to parent chat doc
      const discussionRef = db
        .collection('discussions')
        .doc(context.params.discussionId)

      // 2. Updating the data
      await discussionRef.update({
        totalReplies: firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
      })

      // Return true if everything went fine
      return true
    } catch (error) {
      // Return error if something went wrong
      functions.logger.error(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
      return error
    }
  })
```

```js
{
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "message": "ReferenceError: firestore is not defined\n    at /Users/syedalirazabokhari/Desktop/Development/React/omanshopping/functions/index.js:23:23\n    at cloudFunction (/Users/syedalirazabokhari/Desktop/Development/React/omanshopping/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:23)\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:590:16\n    at runFunction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:577:15)\n    at runBackground (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:589:11)\n    at processBackground (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:572:11)\n    at invokeTrigger (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:647:19)\n    at handleMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:734:15)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"
}
```

I tried to debug the issue but unable to resolve. I have also updated the firebase-admin to the latest version 9.5.0 as of now.

Comment: I don't think it is the cause of your problem, but requiring the same module multiple times seems unusual. Did you consider `const firestore = admin.firestore`?

Comment: I have other cloud functions as well which are working fine but when this specific function is triggered I get this reference error. Yes you are right, I didn't noticed multiple imports. I will try to remove one maybe this is the cause.

Comment: I removed the import but the issue exists. I think (firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)) this line is problematic, but I am not sure. Any idea?

Comment: I even changed it to admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1). But no luck

Comment: I was updating index.js from another project. Thanks to vscode for that. By the way the issue is resolved now. Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the unnecessary import `const { firestore } = require('firebase-admin')` and then changing `firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` to `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` fixed the error.